# Which is the preferred way to filter dataset in Python?

Tags: python, data-processing

Filter dataset 02 telecom_usage.csv with multiple condition

- the value of **CustomerCareCalls** starting with even digits (2, 4, 6 or 8)
- the value of **UnansweredCalls** > **BlockedCalls**

First way:

```
df_2 = pd.read_csv('02 telecom_usage.csv')
df_3 = df_2[(df_2['CustomerCareCalls'].str.contains('^2|^4|^6|^8')&
                 df_2['UnansweredCalls']>df_2['BlockedCalls'])]
```

second way:

```
df_4 = pd.read_csv('02 telecom_usage.csv')
df_5 = df_4[df_4['CustomerCareCalls'].str.contains('^2|^4|^6|^8')]
    df_6 = df_5[df_5['UnansweredCalls']>df_5['BlockedCalls']]]
```

I've tried to run both queries with same dataset, but there are different results in both

the first filter results as many as 160 data from 5000 data, while the results of the second filter are 558 data from 5000 data

after I checked the results manually via excel, the results both met the request for multiple conditions.

I want to know, why the result is difference

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you are concerned about the performance, you can use %timeit to check the performance time for both methods

Comment: These look identical at first glance, except you have `df_2` and `df_4` that you don't define, one would naturally assume they should be the same, but we can't know for sure... and so that's probably where the problem is. [ask] and [mre]